# Push array length remains constant

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am new in react and I want to push values when click Ok of Modal. For example, if i want to add egg drop, and then add Chicken burrito, both of these are added in array in Navbar state  Total_Item.

The problem is that the items are added, but the length of array remain 2. It seems that array size remain constant , and one array is saved in another array. I need to fix the length size, so later i can run logic to keep unique values. Please see Menu component and check Listval() function.

I need to correct the push array logic.Please see the sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/mutable-water-8779d

thanks

App Component

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import "./styles.css";

class App extends Component {
render (){
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <Navbar/>
    </div>
  );


}
   
}

export default App;
```

Navbar Component

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import Menu from "./Menu";

class Navbar extends Component {
  state={
Category:[
  {
    id:1,
    FoodType: "Chinese",
    Menu:["Egg Drop", "Chicken Fried", "Beef Fried"],
    Price:[2,8,10]
    },
    
    {
      id:2,
      FoodType: "Mexican",
      Menu:["Veg Burrito", "Chicken Burrito", "Beef Burrito"],
      Price:[7,8,10]
      }

],

One_Item:[
{
  listvalue:null,
  Select_Item:null,
  Select_Price:null,
  Select_Quantity:null,
  Select_Item_TotalPrice:null

}

],

Cart_Item:[

  {
Total_Item:[]

  }
]



  };




  render() {
    return (

   <Menu
  //  len={this.state.length}
  //  FoodTypes_list = {this.state.map(e => e.FoodType)}
  //  MenuList_list={this.state.map(e => e.Menu)}


Objs_Type={this.state.Category}




  //  FoodTypes={this.state.Type1.FoodType}
  //  MenuList={this.state.Type1.Menu}
 
   />

    );


  }
}
export default Navbar;
```

Menu Component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Modal } from "react-bootstrap";
import NumericInput from "react-numeric-input";

class Menu extends Component {
  state = {
    addModalShow: false,
    copied: false
  };

  ModalShow = () => {
    this.setState({ addModalShow: true });
  };

  async ModalText(e) {
    await this.setState({ listvalue: e.target.innerHTML });

    //  console.log(this.state.listvalue);
  }

  ModalClose = () => {
    this.setState({ addModalShow: false });
  };

  async Listval() {
    let ll = "$" + this.state.listvalue.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");

    let ll2 = this.state.listvalue.replace(/\d+/g, "");
    let ll3 = ll2.replace(/\$/g, "");

    let ll4 = ll.replace(/\$/g, "");
    let ll5 = this.state.Select_Quantity;
    let ll6 = parseFloat(ll4) * ll5;

    let ll7 = [this.state.Total_Item];
    ll7.push(ll3);

    // this.state.ll7.map((e,idx) => {
    //   key={idx}
    // };

    // for(var i=0;i<ll7.length;i++){
    //   // push the component to elements!
    //  return ll7[key=i]
    // };

    // ll7.filter((item,index)=>{
    //   return ll7.indexOf(item)===index
    // });

    // let ll2='$'+ll.replace(/[^0-9]/g,'');
    await this.setState({ Select_Price: ll });
    await this.setState({ Select_Item: ll3 });
    await this.setState({ Select_Item_TotalPrice: ll6 });

    await this.setState({ Total_Item: ll7 });

    console.log(this.state.Total_Item);
  }

  stylesList = {
    display: "inline-block",
    background: "#C8C8C8",
    width: "500px",
    height: "50px"
  };

  onhover = e => {
    e.target.style.background = "red";
  };

  offhover = e => {
    e.target.style.background = "#C8C8C8 ";
  };

  render() {
    return <div className="container-fluid">{this.Mapping_Type()}</div>;
  }

  Mapping_Type() {
    let result_type = this.props.Objs_Type.map(a => a.FoodType);
    let result_menu = this.props.Objs_Type.map(a => a.Menu);
    let result_price = this.props.Objs_Type.map(a => a.Price);

    let newFoodtype = [];
    let newMenu = [];
    let FoodType_Menu = [];
    let Price_new = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < result_type.length; i++) {
      let temp1 = <h1> Menu {result_type[i]}</h1>;
      let temp2 = result_menu[i].map((item, idx) => (
        <div style={this.stylesList}>
          <ul style={{ padding: 0 }}>
            {/* <CopyToClipboard> */}
            <li
              id={idx}
              style={{ listStyleType: "none" }}
              key={item.id}
              className={"listitems"}
              onMouseOver={this.onhover}
              onMouseOut={this.offhover}
              onClick={e => {
                this.ModalShow();
                this.ModalText(e);
              }}
            >
              {" "}
              {item} {result_price[i][idx]}{" "}
            </li>
            {/* </CopyToClipboard> */}

            <Modal
              style={{ opacity: 1 }}
              size="md"
              aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
              show={this.state.addModalShow}
              onHide={this.ModalClose}
            >
              <Modal.Header closeButton>
                <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
                  Large Modal
                </Modal.Title>
              </Modal.Header>
              <Modal.Body>
                <div className="container">
                  {this.state.listvalue}
                  <br />
                  <NumericInput
                    min={1}
                    max={1000}
                    value={this.state.Select_Quantity}
                    onChange={value =>
                      this.setState({ Select_Quantity: value })
                    }
                    style={{ float: "right", width: "500px", padding: "10px" }}
                  />

                  <br />

                  <button
                    class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right"
                    onClick={() => {
                      this.Listval();
                    }}
                  >
                    OK
                  </button>
                </div>
              </Modal.Body>
            </Modal>
          </ul>
        </div>
      ));

      FoodType_Menu.push(temp1, temp2);
    }
    return FoodType_Menu;
  }
}

export default Menu;
```

Comment: may you link the codesandbox?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/mutable-water-8779d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't `Total_Item?` an array itself?

when you do this:

```
let ll7 = [this.state.Total_Item];
```

you are creating an array (`[]`) that *contains* the `Total_Item` array.
And then, with this line:

```
ll7.push(ll3);
```

You push `ll3` into your array. So your array now contains the `Total_Item` array and `ll3`.

If `Total_Item` is an array, it would be:

```
let ll7 = this.state.Total_Item || [];
ll7.push(ll3);
```

Or if you want an independent array, you can use the `...` spread operator:

```
let ll7 = [...(this.state.Total_Item || [])];
ll7.push(ll3);
```

Comment: Philipp thanks, The spread operator is not working here, I need to put [] for ll3, to make it work as an array. This is the error with the spread "Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance"

Comment: This is because it's undefined at the beginning. Try this instead: `let ll7 =  this.state.Total_Item || [];` (answer adjusted)

Comment: Phillip it worked. can you explain more whats happening, Also since you already seen the script. how to further make it unique. That will be my next step. There are many solutions, which on you think is the easiest one.

Comment: By wrapping `[Total_Items]` in brackets (`[]`), you created an array that _contained_ your array, when all you want is the `Total_Items` array itself. So if the length of `Total_Items` was 3, the length of your outer array is still 1 (since it just contains your `Total_Items` array).
I don't know what you mean by unique, but maybe that's beyond the scope of this question?